# Bedeutung "Ich bin gut davor."

Tags: meaning-in-context

Was bedeutet der folgende Satz: "Ich bin gut davor"? Ich habe ihn gehört als ich meiner Kollegin Hilfe angeboten habe.

Comment: Ich bin Norddeutscher und habe diese Redewendung nie gehört und würde sie wohl für einen Fehler halten und nur aus dem Kontext heraus verstehen. Auch zwei Bekannte (aus Ostfriesland und Kiel) können damit nichts anfangen. Das beweist natürlich nichts, aber dennoch wage ich zu behaupten, dass es keine gängige Formulierung ist, oder dass sie regional sehr begrenzt verwendet wird.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Ich komme damit gut zurecht" oder "Ich bin bald damit fertig", je nach Kontext.

Hört man im Kieler Raum ab und an. Ich würde es persönlich nicht benutzen, weil es ein bisschen zu hemdsärmelig klingt. Einerseits schwingt da "Alles im Griff" mit, unter Umständen aber auch ein "Bitte störe mich jetzt nicht und lass mich einfach weitermachen, ich habe jetzt echt keine Zeit zu reden".

Auf jeden Fall würde ich nach solch einer Antwort nicht weiter insistieren, meine Hilfe anbieten.

Comment: Und wenn Du Hemdsärmeligkeit vermitteln willst, dass Du alles im Griff hast und nicht gestört werden willst - würdest Du es dann auch nicht verwenden?

Comment: Touché. Kommt bei mir aber eher selten vor.

Answer (score 6):

In Kiel aufgewachsen und seit bald 25 Jahren in Bremen wohnend verwende ich es heute noch und werde manchmal darauf angesprochen. Ich verwende es, wenn es ein gesetztes Ziel gibt und die Zwischenziele bisher erreicht wurden, so dass es kein Risiko gibt, es nicht zu schaffen. Eher wurde sogar schon mehr erreicht.  „Voll im Plan liegen“ wäre meine Übersetzung anstelle von „kurz davor“. Den Touch von Strombergs „Läuft…!“  hat es aber in keinem Fall! Es ist also durchaus anerkennend gemeint, wenn ich von jemandem sage, er sei gut davor.

Comment: Also von "ich liege gut vor dem Wind"??? Ohne Kreuzen direkt in den Hafen einlaufen? Lieber "gut vor Kiel liegen" als "kurz vor Kiel" mit dem falschen Wind?

Answer (score 2):

Das sagt man im *wirklichen* Norddeutschland, also im Grenzgebiet und auf jeden Fall auch bis Eckernförde runter. Man ist gut davor, wenn man absehen kann, mit etwas fertig zu werden oder es so gut wie fertig ist, oder es für einen gut läuft.

Answer (score 1):

In Nordfriesland wird der Ausdruck gebraucht, wenn man sagt, das es jemandem gut geht..."Er ist zur Zeit gut davor!"